# HDD Problems with superblocks

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance

I bought a new laptop and after moving the home folder successfully I wanted to delete all the partitions from my old one, overwrite everything with bleach and the make a new clean install of ubuntu to my old laptop and give it to a friend.

During installation I chose the following configuration
1 GB Boot
245 GB /
245 GB empty
4 GB SWAP

The installation said that the second partition couldn't be formatted because of some error. I then connected the hard externally to my new laptop and run GParted which also couldn't format it.

After some research I run the command

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sde1 | grep -i superblock
```

and the reply was something like:
Backup superblock at:

> 32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632,
>   2654208, 4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616,
>   78675968,
>   102400000.

Then I run the command

```
e2fsck -f -b -y 32768 /dev/sde1
```

After 2 days straight the command is still running and I don't know what to do, please advise

Is there any faster way to do it?
The hard disk is "empty" 500GB and prior to this I had no problems at all, I was even thinking of using my old HD to my new laptop because I was bored reinstalling ubuntu.

I do not even care about the data it contains

Right now the output is:

> Error reading block 20976926 (Attempt to read block from filesystem
>   resulted in short read) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore
>   error? yes
>
> Force rewrite? yes

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad hard drive. It will only get worse over time. It should be replaced. The fastest way to solve your problem is just get a new drive.